# Reading from same SslStream simultaneously?

Tags: c#, stream, async-await, tcpclient, c#-5.0

I am currently reading XML data from a SslStream. The stream is coming from a TcpClient object.

```
using (XmlReader r = XmlReader.Create(sslStream, new XmlReaderSettings() { Async = true }))                
{
    while (await r.ReadAsync())
    {
        ResetStream = false;
        switch (r.NodeType)
        {
            case XmlNodeType.XmlDeclaration:
                ...
                break;
            case XmlNodeType.Element:
...
```

Additionally I would like to read every single bit and byte from the TcpClient directly regardless whether it is XML data or not. How can I read the same stream twice? Is it possible to read it with the XmlReader *and* dump the stream content somehow?

I would like to see what is coming from the stream and how it is parsed via XmlReader for debugging.

**UPDATE:**

I would like to keep one stream running rather then having two independent streams. Since I already have the data it does not make sense in my application to have it again in the memory.

Comment: How should that look? Two seemingly independent streams? Or would something like one stream and one callback (which gets called the whe stream is read) be enough?

Comment: I updated the question. I would like to manage one stream. Is something like this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a callback for the data that was just read is okay for you, you could create a wrapper `Stream` that does exactly that:

```
public class TeeStream : Stream
{
    private readonly Stream m_underlyingStream;
    private readonly Action<byte[], int> m_readCallback;

    public TeeStream(Stream underlyingStream, Action<byte[], int> readCallback)
    {
        m_underlyingStream = underlyingStream;
        m_readCallback = readCallback;
    }

    public override int Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        var read = m_underlyingStream.Read(buffer, offset, count);

        m_readCallback(buffer, read);

        return read;
    }

    public override async Task<int> ReadAsync(
        byte[] buffer, int offset, int count,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var read = await m_underlyingStream.ReadAsync(
            buffer, offset, count, cancellationToken);

        m_readCallback(buffer, read);

        return read;
    }

    // the remaining members that have to be overridden
    // just call the same member of underlyingStream
}
```

Usage would be something like this:

```
var teeStream = new TeeStream(sslStream, (bytes, read) => /* whatever */);

using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(
    teeStream, new XmlReaderSettings { Async = true }))
…
```

Comment: When I fire an event from the callback and send the data into a windows forms text box then the data is not in the correct order like in the reads from XmlReader. Why is that and how do I get them in correct order?

Comment: @TonyStark How are you sending them to the textbox?

Comment: I am firing an event with the data (converted to UTF8 string) that I handle in the UI. I am using SetTextCallback when the text box has to be invoked. I guess this is some kind of timing problem an setting the text does not finish in some cases.

Answer (score 1):

Implement your own `TeeStream` class derived from `Stream` which has a `MemoryStream` it writes to every time it does a read.

Comment: But this means all of the data has to fit into memory and you can read the second copy only after you finish with the first copy, no? Though it's not clear from the question if that would be a problem.