# Why does Console.WriteLine() block in callback from Stream.ReadAsync()?

Tags: c#, io, console

I have a callback function in which I am trying to write the data that I read in an overriden ReadAsync().

```
private void StreamCallback(byte[] bytes)
{
    Console.WriteLine("--> " + Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes)); // the whole application is blocked here, why?
    if (OnDataReceived != null)
    {
        string data = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
        OnDataReceived(data);
    }
}
```

The overriden ReadAsync() looks as follows.

```
public override async Task<int> ReadAsync(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var read = await _originalStream.ReadAsync(buffer, offset, count, cancellationToken);
    _readCallback(buffer);

     return read;
}
```

What I actually want to achieve is to monitor a network stream just before it gets parsed by an XmlReader. This relates to my other question > [Reading from same SslStream simultaneously?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18329264/reading-from-same-sslstream-simultaneously) <. How would I do that?

**UPDATE**:

It is actually `Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes)` that is blocking the application. In order for the question to be more complete I am listing the code for reading the XML stream.

```
using (XmlReader r = XmlReader.Create(sslStream, new XmlReaderSettings() { Async = true }))                
{
    while (await r.ReadAsync())
    {
        switch (r.NodeType)
        {
            case XmlNodeType.XmlDeclaration:
                ...
                break;
            case XmlNodeType.Element:
...
```

Comment: why don't you try `bytes.ToString()` instead of `Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes)`  or am I missing some basics here?

Comment: @Malachi: What should I do with `System.Byte[]` (which is produced by `ToString()`) then?

Comment: I am not sure that I am following what is supposed to be done here. the `Console.WriteLine()` should just write out the `byte[]`  so telling it to print the equivalent of `byte[]` as `char[]` shouldn't change what you are doing there?  your `OnDataRecieved` should probably take a `byte[]` and not a string (`char[]`) is what I am thinking.  I could be very wrong. just trying to understand what exactly is going on

Comment: What's the size of bytes(I mean bytes.Length)

Comment: @Malachi `Encoding.GetString()` converts bytes to human readable string representation! Did you get my point?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: 65536 bytes.

Comment: try `Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes).ToString()` the `Encoding.GetString()` returns a `System.String` which has a Method of `ToString()` I imagine it should work in this instance.

Comment: i am sorry about my first comment. I wasn't meaning to be rude, I just re read it, i meant that I didn't know if I was out in left field or not by saying "am I missing some basics here"

Comment: @Malachi: Nope. It continues to block with your suggestion.

Comment: you mean it freezes?  does it give an error? please add the error if there was one, I will thinka bout it over lunch

Comment: @Malachi: There is absolutely no exception. Yes it freezes/blocks as if it would wait for more input.

Comment: Does it continues after sometime? or blocks forever?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: Well it blocks for a minute and more for sure. I cannot check "forever" :)

Comment: @Malachi: The result of `bytes.ToString()` is "System.Byte[]". There is no automatic conversion of a byte array to a string. You have to call an `Encoding.GetString` method so that it can interpret the bytes.

Comment: @TonyStark: What are the other threads doing? In particular, is one of them waiting on console input (i.e. `Console.ReadKey` or `Console.ReadLine`)
?

Comment: @JimMischel: Well I am using `XmlReader.ReadAsync()` in the same class as the callback function. You can take a look at the linked question.

Comment: If so, see this bug report:  See this bug report: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/778650/undocumented-locking-behaviour-in-system-console

Comment: @JimMischel: I don't think it is a `Console` bug. It is the same when I call `_log.debug();` and `_log` is an `log4net` instance.

Comment: My money is on the console lock as well.  You'll need to post a stack trace of the thread, the complete one you see in the Call Stack debugger window.  And enable Windows Update on your machine to get the console lock problem to disappear automagically.

Comment: Make sure your app is multithreaded. remember that Console.WriteLine is actually writing to a stream and you may only have one IO thread in play.

Comment: @JoeCaffeine, the app is multithreaded. ReadAsync is already an async task and streamcallback must run it either the UI or some other thread.

Comment: @HansPassant - nope, no console lock issue needed. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the code you posted, StreamCallback() will block until that stream ends. You pass a byte pointer to Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes); So, it needs to keep querying bytes until it reaches the end. It will never reach the end since bytes comes from a stream until that stream is closed.

You need to either process your stream a certain number of bytes at a time or until a certain character is seen.